# What kind is that sentence and is it correct?

Tags: questions

Which is correct? :

> 1- You do not know who you will fall in love with.
>
> 2- You do not know who will you fall in love with

.
 and

> 1- You do not know where you will live.
>
> 2- You do not know where will you live.

Answer (score 1):

You first sentence is almost correct

> You do not know who**m** you will fall in love with.

Your this sentence is correct

> You do not know where you will live.

The problem with the other sentences is

> who will you fall in love with
>    where will you live

that word ordering is in the form of a question.

Comment: I think *who* is also OK here.